# QGIS 3.0 Convert a text field to a numerical field retaining the number but losing square brackets?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator

I tagged all my drawing objects with a identifier which includes square brackets. eg [302] [303] [509].

Edit to add further information.

- Not all objects are tagged with brackets.
- A few are tagged with just numbers eg 425, 359.
- A few are tagged Furrow
- A few are tagged Z
- a few are tagged I
- A few are tagged G?
- A few are tagged multiple ditches
- There may be a few others sometimes.

Is there a code which could read the [number] from the text field and paste the number (without the brackets) into the numerical field?

Edit - if possible the tags that are already numbers would transfer as they are, while any purely text can be left blank.

If there is such a code, how and where would I input it?

Comment: Dont name the new field "2". Try "field2" or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>A bit ugly, but this should work in the field calculator:</s>

```
toint( replace(replace("yourfield", ']', ''), '[', '') )
```

This will create an numeric (integer) field with the number between the brackets.

*Edit:* I believe this expression will work for your tags:

```
if(regexp_substr( "input", '(\\d+)') <> '', toint(regexp_substr("input", '(\\d+)')), NULL)
```

This converts :

- [number] to number,
- number to number,
- any text to NULL,
- NULL to NULL.

Comment: Any solution will do. I just assumed it might involve Python.
I can't even duplicate a field in the field calculator, and have no idea how to use your code. Sorry, and thanks.
How do I tell it which attribute to copy and where to paste the amended version?

Comment: Well, there is a nice [tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) on QGIS website which explains how to use it. You just have to copy the expression I wrote into the "Expression" field, replace `yourfield` with the name of the text field containing the number with bracket, and choose the result field name in "Output field name".

Comment: I've managed to make a copy of the field (as a text field and with all the numbers) . I relaced yourfield in the code with that field name, but the calculator says that the expression is invalid.
The new field is named 1 and I used this code 
toint( replace(replace("1", ']', ''), '[', '') )

Comment: I tried it as you suggest above, but it still says that the expression is invalid.

Comment: I am not sure that "1" is a valid field name, and I am a bit surprised that you were able to create a field with this name. You don't really need to copy the input field, the field calculator will automatically create a new output field if you check the "Create a new field" checkbox.

Comment: I tried that. I've added an image in my original post to show the field calculator. It happily accepts a number as a field name. It's the expression it won't accept.
I tried a different field name (test) but the expression still says it's invalid.

Comment: I am completely lost then, sorry :( I just retried with the exact same expression I wrote, with the right version of QGIS (3.0), and this works fine. I really can't figure out why you get this error... One last thing i'd like to check: are you sure to have only one number (with brackets) per row?

Comment: Oh. Could that be it? There are a few objects without brackets. A very few are just numbers, some are text. I didn't realise they would cause a problem. Maybe this is too complicated to be do-able. The numbers would have to transfer as they are, and the text entries would need a null value in the new field. I didn't think about that.
Thanks for trying.

Comment: This could definitively be the issue ;) Could you please add to your question a copy of your objects tags (or a representative part of it if the list is too long)? There is probably a way to deal with the variety of input formats, using a different expression than the one I came up with.

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if there is still any issue.

Comment: Success. I've marked your answer as the solution. Thank you for your help.